# Get a filtered list of objects defined inside a MongoDB document

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I work with Spring Boot and MongoDB. I am looking for a solution to get a list of hobbies but not all of them. The hobbies have to meet the conditions (name or description have to include searched phrase).

```
@Document("persons")
@Data
class Person {
    @Id
    private String personId;
    private String name;
    private List<Hobby> hobbies;
}
```

```
@Data
class Hobby {
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String notImportantField;
}
```

**Example**

I want to get a person with reduced list of hobbies (all the hobbies have to contain searched phrase in one of its field).

*Person document from the database*

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("id1"),
    "name" : "some person",
    "hobbies" : [
        {
            "name" : "A",
            "description" : "AB",
            "notImportantField" : "ABCDEF"
        },
        {
            "name" : "ABC",
            "description" : "ABCD",
            "notImportantField" : "ABCDEF"
        }
    ]
}
```

What I want to receive:

- I want person with id `id1` and I am looking for phrase `ab` in person's hobbies. I should get **a list with 2 hobbies** (first hobby's description contains `ab`, second hobby's name and description contains `ab`)
- I want person with id `id1` and I am looking for phrase `d` in person's hobbies. I should get **a list with 1 hobby** (second hobby's description contains `d`)

I tried something like this but I get a person with all of its hobbies.

```
@Repository
interface PersonRepository extends MongoRepository<Person, String> {
    @Query("{'$and': [" +
                "{'_id': :#{#personId}}," +
                "{'$or':[" +
                    "{'hobbies.name': {$regex: :#{#searchPhraseRegex}, $options: 'i'}}," +
                    "{'hobbies.description': {$regex: :#{#searchPhraseRegex}, $options: 'i'}}" +
                "]}" +
            "]}")
    List<Person> method(@Param("personId") String personId, @Param("searchPhraseRegex") String searchPhraseRegex);
}
```

The result method should return a person with filtered hobbies or only list of hobbies.
Thanks in advance for help.

**UPDATE: RESOLVED**

Thanks @user20042973 for the help :) I used your query and change it a little to match my query in Mongo repository. It works as I expected. The result method is:

```
@Repository
interface PersonRepository extends MongoRepository<Person, String> {
    @Aggregation(pipeline = {
            "{'$match': {'_id': :#{#personId}}}",
            "{'$addFields':  {'hobbies': {'$filter': {" +
                    "'input': '$hobbies', " +
                    "'cond': " +
                        "{'$or': [" +
                            "{'$regexMatch': {'input': '$$this.name', 'regex': :#{#searchPhraseRegex}, 'options': 'i' }}," +
                            "{'$regexMatch': {'input': '$$this.description', 'regex': :#{#searchPhraseRegex}, 'options': 'i' }}" +
                        "]}" +
                    "}}}}"
    })
    Optional<Person> findPersonByIdAndFilterHobbies(@Param("personId") String personId, @Param("searchPhraseRegex") String searchPhraseRegex);
}
```

Note: For searching e.g. `ab` we need to pass `.*ab.*` as a method argument `searchPhraseRegex`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helpfully, getting a filtered list of objects from an array can be done using [the `$filter` operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/). The operator takes an array as input and can process each item individually via an expression. In your situation that expression would include a `$regexMatch` to look for the value in the string(s) of interest. So the stage would look something like this:

```
  {
    "$addFields": {
      hobbies: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$hobbies",
          cond: {
            $or: [
              {
                $regexMatch: {
                  input: "$$this.name",
                  regex: "d",
                  options: "i"
                }
              },
              {
                $regexMatch: {
                  input: "$$this.description",
                  regex: "d",
                  options: "i"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Sample Mongo Playground example is [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uMrNtU2osCq).

From your question it's not quite clear if you will separately be using this as selection criteria for the document itself.  I've left the leading `$match` stage to just use `_id` for the moment, but of course you can add any other filters to it (such as `'hobbies.name': /d/i`) as needed.

I'm not personally familiar enough with Spring Boot to say what the exact syntax is to create such a pipeline, but I do know that aggregations are supported.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I updated my question. There's now the query to use in MongoRepository with @Aggregation annotation